# One by Wacom installing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, xorg, tablet, wacom

I cannot make ubuntu 16.06 LTS recognize my new Wacom One device. It is actually recognized from usb.

```
>> lsusb
>> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 056a:037b Wacom Co., Ltd
```

However in the system settings > hardware > wacom tablet, there is no tablet detected.

I have also tried `install xserver-xorg-input-wacom` but I have some dependency problems.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom : Depends: xorg-input-abi-22
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install those dependencies manually but I was not sure if I was doing right due to the warning about the removing of some serious other packages.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxfont2 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop xorg xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 18 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1 344 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5 702 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So, I am stuck here. Any suggestion?

Update: I have solved detection issue by following [this link](https://linuxwacom.github.io/). I still find it quite hassle. It would be so nice to have a ppa but, well, it works now so here is my steps:

- Downloaded [input-wacom-0.45.0.tar.bz2](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases)
  .
- Extracted into a folder and computed:

  ```
  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
  ```

However, still I can't make the system detect the tabled as xinput properly. I don't have pressure sensitivity although my device is in the list of xinputs.

```
>> xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Melfas LGDisplay Incell Touch             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0818:00 044E:121F Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0818:00 044E:121F Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom One by Wacom M Pen stylus           id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom One by Wacom M Pen eraser           id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I have computed as it is stated in the [link](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver):

```
    sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom$(dpkg -S $(which Xorg) | grep -Eo -- "-hwe-[^:]*")"
```

which gives me `xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04 is already the newest version (1:0.34.0-0ubuntu2~16.04.1).`

Now I am still stuck in pressure sensitivity.

Comment: The  `xserver-xorg-core` package available meets the requirements (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial-updates&searchon=names&keywords=xserver-xorg-core) but you have *held broken packages*, ie. prior errors you ignored that need correction first.  Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` and other messages you probably were suggested as fixes.  Can you please provide `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core` results (*it feels like you have unofficial sources creating your issues, at least to me*)

Comment: Did you tried to install newer driver with `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04` was a packaage that I have already installed but didn't solve my problem. Eventually, I made it work as I described in the answer.

Comment: How are you testing for pressure sensitivity? Some applications like GIMP require jumping through hoops before they respond to the hardware pressure.