# One by Wacom does not work in Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, tablet, wacom

I purchased a One by Wacom tablet and it does not work in my Ubuntu laptop. This means, in particular,

1. `lsusb` returns `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 056a:037b Wacom Co., Ltd`
2. *Wacom Tablet* in **Devices** in **Settings** says *no stylus found* at the stylus tab and *no tablet detected* at the tablet tab (and nothing at the test your settings tab)
3. `xsetwacom --list devices` returns nothing
4. `xinput list` returns

   ```
   Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)] 
   ⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ELAN0732:00 04F3:2B2C                      id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Video Bus                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                               id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ HP Wide Vision HD: HP Wide Visi            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                             id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                        id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ```

   so nothing if I am not mistaken
5. `libwacom-list-local-devices  | grep -A4 Name` returns

   ```
   Name=Wacom Serial Tablet WACf004
   DeviceMatch=serial:0000:0000;
   Class=ISDV4
   Width=0
   Height=0
   --
   Name=One by Wacom (medium)
   DeviceMatch=usb:056a:037b;
   Class=Bamboo
   Width=9
   Height=5
   ```
6. `sudo modinfo wacom` returns

   ```
   filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-96-generic/extra/wacom.ko
   license:        GPL
   description:    USB Wacom tablet driver
   author:         Vojtech Pavlik <vojtech@ucw.cz>
   version:        v2.00-0.45.0
   srcversion:     0AA19FE5A3E9C50CD127943
   ```

   Then a bunch of aliases and then, at the end of it,

   ```
   depends:        hid,usbhid
   retpoline:      Y
   name:           wacom
   vermagic:       4.15.0-96-generic SMP mod_unload 
   parm:           touch_arbitration: on (Y) off (N) (bool)
   ```
7. `dmesg | grep -i wacom` returns

   ```
   [ 9080.235729] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
   [ 9080.298106] input: Wacom Co.,Ltd. CTL-672 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:056A:037B.0006/input/input25
   [ 9080.299605] hid-generic 0003:056A:037B.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Wacom Co.,Ltd. CTL-672] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
   [ 9080.306874] hid-generic 0003:056A:037B.0007: hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. CTL-672] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
   ```

I apologize if some of the above are irrelevant; I just took a long time through any forum and question that looked close to my problems, and those commands appeared from time to time.

I have of course tried everything I found, starting with https://linuxwacom.github.io/ as well as things along the lines of [One by Wacom installing in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199024/one-by-wacom-installing-in-ubuntu-16-04) .

I am more of a basic Ubuntu user but I can follow instructions to the best of my ability :) Any suggestions would be **really** appreciated.

Comment: It looks like https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2435858 has the same issue (not the duplicates one).

Comment: Wow! Such a nicely researched and reported question, especially for a new contributor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I managed to figure out a solution and now my tablet is at least working with xournal, for example.

First of all, I updated my kernel from 4.15.0-96-generic to 5.3.0-46-generic following the steps described here:

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/how-to-install-ubuntu-18042-lts.html

I am only mentioning this here in case it helps someone else, but in my case I don't *think* this played any role.

The real problem seemed to be Secure Boot. Namely, a friend found this

https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/77

to which my problem was a match, therefore I followed this

https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Secure-Boot

and checked that indeed when I disabled my Secure Boot from BIOS the tablet worked. Then I followed the steps regarding the keys, and finally I re-built input-wacom from source following

https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source

but now adding the secure boot keys, namely I used the command

`if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh --with-signing-key=/root/MOK.priv; else ./configure --with-signing-cert=/root/MOK.der; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"`

Comment: For me it wasn't Secure Boot, but the kernel that was the issue, on an older 18.04 laptop that I tried first. Thanks to your tip about the kernel, I got it working (after wasting a bunch of time trying other things before I found this question). On a newer laptop with 18.04 (already had a 5.3.0 kernel), the One by Wacom worked right away.

Comment: Really glad the kernel worked for you!

Comment: For me updating the kernel to hwe and then doing `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04` did the job.

Comment: The Linux kernel gained support for the One by Wacom in version 4.16 ([see here](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs)). The v4.15 kernel that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 does not support it, but the v5.3 kernel which comes with the HWE stack does. Installing the "input-wacom" driver is usually only necessary if you cannot update your Linux kernel to a version with native support.

Answer (score 12):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my computer. I have just bought Wacom One Medium to my kid, and it works flawless right out of the box. It is the newest linux, and an old and simple model of drawing tablet - I am not sure whether it would work with more sophisticated models, but this is pure plug'n'play experience.
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I am using One by Wacom CTL-672 on ubuntu 18.04 system and is also just plug and use.